# Is it possible to trigger a FCM push notification based on an expiry date in Firestore Database?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build an Android app using Kotlin that sends a push notification to the user's device using FCM in Firebase when one of their items are expiring soon. However, I have not been able to figure out how to trigger the notification based on the expiry date stored in the Firestore Database for a specific item. In Firebase -> Engage -> Cloud Messaging -> Notifications -> New Notification, it seems like you can only schedule a notification based on a fixed date.

Is there a way to trigger the notification based on a value stored in the Firestore Database instead?

Logic should be:
If current_date > expiry_date then trigger push notification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore does not feature any such event, but one can schedule a Cloud Function:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions